# What exactly does rewind() do?

Tags: c, rewind

I came across the `rewind()` function in C. I went through its description and example from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rewind.htm).

The description mentioned the following about the function:

> The C library function `void rewind(FILE *stream)` sets the file position to the beginning of the file of the given stream.

I really didn't get the idea clear yet. Can we imagine it as a cursor moving in the file to be read, and `rewind()` simply sets that cursor to the beginning of the file?

Comment: It's the same as `fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET)`, and does exactly what you expect it to do. See also e.g. [this `rewind` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind), or [this `fseek` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek).

Comment: basically the answer is yes

Comment: Your explanation of a cursor sounds pretty good to me - `fseek` is the function to position that cursor more freely.

Comment: Have you ever seen a magnetic tape?

Comment: It works like `fseek`, an important distinction is that it does not provide an error code, so you will not know if it failed. Not all streams can be seeked or rewound: usually `stdin` can't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rewind):

> The  rewind()  function sets the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream to the beginning of the file.   It  is  equivalent to:
>
> ```
>       (void)fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET)
> ```
>
> except  that  the  error  indicator for the stream is also cleared (see
>          `clearerr(3)`).

So the next time you read from a file after calling `rewind`, you start reading from the beginning.  So your cursor analogy is a valid one.

Comment: If I read() should I call rewind() in case file needs to be read again?

Comment: @the_prole If you want to read the file from the beginning, yes.